What is the area of a resistor?
I get confused every time in series and parallel questions. When two resistors are connected in series the area of combined resistors remains constant, and length gets doubled, while in parallel questions the area gets added up. What is area here? Can you explain with an image? Also, explain about volume, too.

What do you mean the area of a resistor?

I have voted to reopen this question. It seems clear to me exactly what the Op is asking.

Also voting to reopen. This is a perfectly clear question.

The area you ask about, is the cross sectional area of the resistor and is the cut area you get if you literally cut the resistor in half orthogonal to direction the current flows.

For example if the resistors are cylindrical as in the diagram above, then the cross sectional area is the circular blue area at the ends of each resistor.

In this second example, the resistors are in parallel. The current from plus to minus splits and flows through both resistors side by side and the effective cross sectional area is the sum of the two cross sectional areas.
The equation for adding resistors in a parallel is
$R_{total} = \frac{(R_1 \times R_2)}{(R_1 +R_2)}.$
For two 1 Ohm resistors in parallel, the total resistance is:
$R_{total} = \frac{(1 \times 1)}{(1 +1)} = \frac{1}{2} $ Ohms.
Since we know the resistance of a resistor is inversely proportional to its cross sectional area, we can note that the cross sectional area of the resistors is twice the area of a single resistor (in this case) and so the total resistance is 1/2 Ohm, just as we obtained above, using the fancy formula.
The volume of a resistor is simply its length multiplied by its cross sectional area. This is not a very useful quantity on its own, in the context of resistors. For example if two resistors are made of the same material with the same resistivity ($\rho =1$) then if R1 has length 4 and area 2 then its volume is 4$\times$ 2 = 8  and if R2 has length 8 and area 4, then its volume is 8$\times$ 4 = 32. R2 has 4 times the volume of R1 and yet it has the same resistance.

Thank you sir for such a clear explanation I got it.

You are welcome. I thinks perhaps you were thinking in terms of surface area instead of cross sectional area and that is why things were not adding up for you. Glad to have helped you clear things up.

yeah you are right silly me. I will try to be more attentive next time.

In the context of resistors and electrical resistance, "area" usually means cross-sectional area - for example, a wire with a circular cross-section and diameter $D$ will have a cross-sectional area of $\frac {\pi D^2} 4$.
You can think of the resistance of a resistor as being proportional to its length and inversely proportional to its cross-sectional area, so that
$\displaystyle R = \rho \frac l A$
(the constant of proportionality $\rho$ is called resistivity).
But this is not the usual way to think of resistors , which are not necessarily all made of the same material. If thinking about length and area is confusing you, best to forget it and simply use Ohm's law.
